# Использование побитовых операций для регулировки прав пользователей

Tags: база-данных, битовые-операции

Понимаю, что такие вопросы здесь не особо приветствуются, но всё-же:

Есть определённая база пользователей. У пользователей могут быть определённые привилегии. Гарантируется, что количество привилегий не более 32.

Разумно ли вместо создания отдельных таблиц ролей и привилегий создать отдельную колонку в таблице пользователей, типа `int` и задать каждому БИТУ маски этого числа определённую привилегию, а также написать отдельный `enum`, в котором будут описаны названия и коды привилегий, а внутри этого `enum`'а функцию, которая будет брать отдельный бит этого числа и сравнивать с кодом указанной привилегии, путём вычисления с помощью выражения `((x >> n) & 1) == 1`, где `x` - это маска числа и `n` - номер бита, отвечающего за привилегию (её код).

Критерии:

- Читаемость кода
- Скорость работы

Примечание: это применяется к реальному продукту, который будет в дальнейшем поддерживаться

Comment: как ты будешь определять какой именно бит за какую роль отвечает?

Comment: хардкод. В enum прокомментирую каждое значение

Comment: Ключевой  вопрос: а это реально даст увеличение скорости?  Ведь проверять привилегии, прежде чем разрешить что-то сделать, все равно придется. Только вместо простой проверки переменной придется сначала провести битовые вычисления. Не могу сказать что это плохая идея, просто нужно аккуратно оценить плюсы и минусы.

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов по-идее прирост должен быть. Побитовые операции, как правило, быстрее базовых арифметических операций.

Классический подход предполагает заводить отдельную таблицу ролей и добавлять туда записи для каждой из ролей. Для проверки на наличие привилегий необходимо: 1) установить соединение с БД 2) получить строчку привилегии 3) получить пользователя 4) проверить наличие привилегий 5) закрыть соединение с БД

В варианте с битами: 1) открыть соединение с БД 2) получить пользователя 3) побитово проверить наличие привилегии 4) закрыть соединение

Comment: @Semior, тогда может просто взять и проверить? Читаемость вещь такая... условная несколько. Одному лучше так другому иначе. А вот скорость можно взять и померять

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов public static boolean CheckPrivilege(User user, Privilege privilege){return ((user.getPrivileges() >> privilege.getCode()) & 1) == 1; }
по-моему не слишком сложно для чтения, конечно, если не писать в одну строчку

Comment: @Seminor, на мой вкус тоже, но дам руку на отсечение - найдутся те ,кому не понравится )

Comment: @Semior, вообще если уже так делать, то делать один `&` и сравнивать с `0` например, сдвиг не нужен

Comment: @Grundy не понял, это как вы собираетесь сравнивать биты числа без сдвига? пример дайте, пожалуйста

Comment: @Semior, точно также как ты сейчас это делаешь

Comment: @Grundy если я хочу получить 3-й бит числа 2, то с чем ты его сравнивать собираешься? 2 & 2 = 2, а не 0; 2 & 0 = 0;

Пример под кат, пожалуйста

Comment: @Semior, Третий бит - это 100 - это 8 - соответственно 2 & 8 => 0

Comment: @Grundy ты предлагаешь заводить коды привилегий в виде степеней двойки? Тогда тут нечитаемость гарантированна xd

Степень двойки укажет, который бит влияет на наличие той или иной привилегии, но только в двоичном представлении

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95952/discussion-between-semior-and-grundy).